# Android emulator working - but app won't run

Tags: android, emulation

I am currently developing an Android app with android studio but since I installed an update yesterday - the emulator stopped working. I reinstalled the whole studio today including all the SDKs, but it's still not working.

As soon as I run the application, the emulator starts but the App is neither installed nor it runs. Not even a complete empty project (hello world) will be started on the emulator.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I might fix this problem - or is familiar with this?

Comment: What does Android Studio's console say when you try to run the app?

Comment: In the emulator: First is said nothing - after the reinstallation the message "process system isn't responding" (but not everytime - depending on what settings I choose for the emulator. But the most time, there is no message.

I'm actually not at home - I'll try it once more to see what the console says

Comment: so I tried it once more with an empty activity (hello world) ... in the emulator: "Process system isn't responding" and a long log-file. what do you want to see? I haven't change anything - I use the API 22 because in the gradle file the SDK version is 22 ..